# Plotly: How to display Axis ticks in hexadecimal?

Tags: python, plotly

In plotly, is there a way to display a given axis' ticks in hexadecimal format rather than as a large scientific number? This is useful to plot address traces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `[str(hex(elem)) for elem in [1000000, ..., 5000000]`

**Plot:**

[image]

**Some details to be aware of:**

To my knowledge you'll have to use a list of type string to obtain the desired behavior. Values such as `[1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000]` will by default be displayed as:

[image]

And that will happen even for `[str(hex(elem)) for elem in xVals]`. So you'll have to explicitly instruct plotly to display the ticks as strings with:

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = xHex,
                 ticktext= xHex)
```

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.express as px

xVals = [1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000]

xHex = [str(hex(elem)) for elem in xVals]

fig = px.scatter(x=xHex, y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()

fig.update_xaxes(tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = xHex,
                 ticktext= xHex)
```

Comment: Thanks @vestland for your answer! Your solution worked for me with a slight modification. Since I have millions of data points I had to sample just a few values: 


`xHex = [str(hex(int(elem))) for elem in np.linspace(xVals.min(), xVals.max(), nticks)]`

Comment: Actually, how do I dynamically update the ticks when I zoom in or out? With the current solution, the ticks are static.

Comment: @DiastolicDuke I'm not sure, actually! Please consider posting that as its own question. Maybe one of the devs comes along with an answer.